# Hide parent if no child views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `Section` with a header and its displayed even if the `Section` has no child views. How can I automatically hide the `Section` if it does not have any child views?

```
Section(header: Text("Header")) {
    // No child views
}
```

Comment: I am sure you know any factors to determine whether the Section can get some child views or not. you can put the Section code into `if` condition with some conditional statements.

Comment: @KyokookHwang Yeah I ended up doing that. Fortunately I had known factors